How to change the DevExpress Gridcontrol cell value in MouseDown WPF
I am using DevExpress WPF GridControl.
Requirement: I have two field (Name and Salary) in the GridControl. Salary type is double. While I enter the value in Salary like 2M, it should be multiplied with million and display like 2,000,000.
So I used the key down event and applied my logic. Below is my code.
XAML:
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridControl" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
                >
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView x:Name="view" AutoWidth="True" ShowTotalSummary="False"
                       KeyDown="view_KeyDown" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name">
        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            <dxe:TextEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Salary" x:Name="salary" >
        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            <dxe:TextEditSettings MaskType="Numeric" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                                  dxe:NumericMaskOptions.AlwaysShowDecimalSeparator="False" 
                                                  Mask="###,###,###,###,##0.####"
                                                  MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" 
                                                  AllowNullInput="True"
                                                  />
        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl>

C#:
string text;
        double finalResult;
        private void view_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var gv = sender as TableView;
            var rowIndex = gv.FocusedRowHandle;
            var columnIndex = gv.DataControl.CurrentColumn.VisibleIndex;

            if (gv.DataControl.CurrentColumn.Name == "salary")
            {


                if (e.Key.ToString().ToUpper() == "M")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        double salaryNum = Convert.ToDouble(text);

                        int million = 1000000;

                        finalResult = salaryNum * million;

                        gridControl.SetCellValue(rowIndex, salary, finalResult);
                        gridControl.RefreshData();

                        text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Key.ToString().ToUpper() == "K")
                {
                }
                else
                {                    
                    switch (e.Key)
                    {
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D0:
                            text = text + "0";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D1:
                            text = text + "1";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D2:
                            text = text + "2";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D3:
                            text = text + "3";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D4:
                            text = text + "4";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D5:
                            text = text + "5";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D6:
                            text = text + "6";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D7:
                            text = text + "7";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D8:
                            text = text + "8";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.D9:
                            text = text + "9";
                            break;
                        case System.Windows.Input.Key.OemPeriod:
                            text = text + ".";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                text = string.Empty;
            }
        }   

ViewModel:
public class MainViewModel {
        public virtual ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel() {
            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            Employees.Add(new Employee("A1", 120000));
            Employees.Add(new Employee("B1", 200000));
            Employees.Add(new Employee("C1", 450000));
            Employees.Add(new Employee("D1", 350000));
            Employees.Add(new Employee("E1", 150000));
        }
    }
    public class Employee {

        public Employee(string emp, double sal)
        {
            this.Name = emp;
            this.Salary = sal;
        }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

I can't update the result in ValueChanged event. Because when I enter "M" key, it is not updated in UI and value changed event is not triggered. So, I am trying to update the final result in keyDown event.
Note: I can't change the Salary field from double to string type as I maintain the number format.
Please share your suggestion on this.
Thanks,
Bharathi.
